# Como pegar o elemento html que se encontra um determinado texto?

Tags: javascript, html

Fala pessoal, tudo bem? Estou tentando resolver a seguinte questão, mas não estou conseguindo. Será que alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda?

Eu preciso pegar o element html onde um determinando texto se encontra. Ou seja, eu percorro uma certo bloco html, encontro o texto que eu preciso, mas eu não achei uma forma de pegar o elemento html para realizar uma determinação ação nele, exemplo inserir uma classe ou remover a mesma.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

```
<div class="bloco1">
  <span>texto 1</span>
  <span>texto 2</span>
  <span>texto 3</span>
</div>
```

Gostaria de percorrer o elemento da classe bloco1 encontrar o texto 1. No span deste texto eu gostaria de inserir ou remover uma classe.

Grato pela ajuda!

Comment: Olha andei pesquisando com JQuery, espero que lhe ajude: https://api.jquery.com/children/ Manipulando esse os span dentro da Class bloco1 você pode adicionar ou remover css nos <span>

Answer (score 1):

Até onde eu sei, existem queries para procurar elementos por `id`, `tag`, `classe`, `atributo`, mas não HTML interno. Você terá que fazer um tradicional laço `for`. Faça um `getElementsByClassName` ou `querySelector` para buscar seu elemento `bloco1`, depois faça um `for` nos filhos (`children`) desse elemento.

Compare o HTML interno (`innerHTML`) ou texto interno (`innerText`) com a string que você está procurando, e se encontrar, adicione a classe nesse elemento.

A diferença entre HTML interno e texto interno é que o texto escapa de `tags` HTML, então se você tiver um elemento como `<span><strong>Texto</strong></span>`, o HTML interno desse elemento será `<strong>Texto</strong>`, mas o texto interto será `Texto`.

```js
var bloco1 = document.querySelector('.bloco1')

// Exemplo utilizando laço for
for (var span of bloco1.children)
  if (span.innerText === 'texto 1')
    span.classList.add('red')

// Exemplo utilizando métodos do array
Array.from(bloco1.children)
  .filter(span => span.innerText === 'texto 3')
  .forEach(span => span.classList.add('orange'))
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

.orange {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="bloco1">
  <span>texto 1</span>
  <span>texto 2</span>
  <span>texto 3</span>
  <span>texto 1</span>
  <span>texto 2</span>
  <span>texto 3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, funcionou certinho as opções!